# Absolute value sort, using a custom comparator

Tags: c++, sorting, lambda

**Background:**

I was asked this question on a pramp interview and I could not pass all the test cases.

**Question:**

> **Absolute Value Sort**
>
> Given an array of integers arr, write a function absSort(arr), that sorts the array according to the absolute values of the numbers in arr. If two numbers have the same absolute value, sort them according to sign, where the negative numbers come before the positive numbers.
>
> Examples:
>
> input:  arr = [2, -7, -2, -2, 0]
>
> output: [0, -2, -2, 2, -7]

**My attempt:**

```
  std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [](int a, int b) {
    if(abs(a) < abs(b))
      return true;
    return a < b ? (a < 0 && abs(a) > b) : (b < 0 && abs(b) > a);
  });
```

I pass some of the test cases but not all for example

```
Input: [2,-7,-2,-2,0]
Expected: [0,-2,-2,2,-7]
Actual: [0, -2, -7, 2, -2 ]
```

I feel like there is just a few minor adjustments I need to make to my lambda function but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java, no stream/lambdas:

```
public int [] sort(int [] nums) {
    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int minIndex = i;
        for (int j = i; j < nums.length; j++) {
           if (Math.abs(nums[j]) < Math.abs(nums[minIndex])) {
              minIndex = j;
           } else if (Math.abs(nums[j]) == Math.abs(nums[minIndex])){
              if (nums[j] < nums[minIndex]) {
                 minIndex = j;
              }
           }
        }
        if (minIndex != i) {
            temp = nums[minIndex];
            nums[minIndex] = nums[i];
            nums[i] = temp;
        }

    }
    return nums;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This might work

```
    std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [](int a, int b) {
    if(abs(a) != abs(b))
      return abs(a) < abs(b);
    return a < b;
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

The comparator for `std::sort` is **not** an arbitrary binary function. It should [establish strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). Otherwise, the behaviour is undefined.

Let's take a look at the comparator (previously suggested, now corrected)

```
bool comp(int a, int b) {
    if (std::abs(a) != std::abs(b))
        return std::abs(a) < std::abs(b);
    return (a < 0);
}
```

The first property of weak order is:

> For all `a`, `comp(a, a) == false`

This property fails for `a = -1`: `comp(-1, -1) == true`.

So this `comp` does not define weak ordering and invoking `std::sort` with it leads to undefined behaviour!